# Finding a uniq -c substitute for big files

Tags: bash, shell, uniq, gnu-toolchain, linux-toolchain

I have a large file (50 GB) and I could like to count the number of occurrences of different lines in it. Normally I'd use

```
sort bigfile | uniq -c
```

but the file is large enough that sorting takes a prohibitive amount of time and memory. I could do

```
grep -cfx 'one possible line'
```

for each unique line in the file, but this would mean n passes over the file for each possible line, which (although much more memory friendly) takes even longer than the original.

Any ideas?

---

A [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15493774/341362) asks about a way to *find* unique lines in a big file, but I'm looking for a way to *count* the number of instances of each -- I already know what the possible lines are.

Comment: Arguably this is a degenerate case of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502177/how-to-count-number-of-unique-values-of-a-field-in-a-tab-delimited-text-file; the http://stackoverflow.com/a/22250460/14122 answer is pretty much exactly what we already have, only picking out a column rather than using the whole line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `awk`

```
awk '{c[$0]++} END {for (line in c) print c[line], line}' bigfile.txt
```

This is O(n) in time, and O(unique lines) in space.

Comment: Arguably, this fills the "port this logic to awk" request in my bash version. :)

Comment: bigfile.txt can be an awk command argument no input redirection is required.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq) 1.5.  It is essentially the same as the awk solution, both in approach and performance characteristics, but the output is a JSON object representing the hash.  (The program can be trivially modified to produce output in an alternative format.)

Invocation:

```
$ jq -nR 'reduce inputs as $line ({}; .[$line] += 1)' bigfile.txt
```

If bigfile.txt consisted of these lines:

```
a
a
b
a
c
```

then the output would be:

```
{
  "a": 3,
  "b": 1,
  "c": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
# port this logic to awk or ksh93 to make it fast

declare -A counts=( )
while IFS= read -r line; do
  counts[$line]=$(( counts[$line] + 1 )) # increment counter
done

# print results
for key in "${!counts[@]}"; do
  count=${counts[$key]}
  echo "Found $count instances of $key"
done
```

Comment: How does `grep` help, it will match all the lines?

Comment: @Barmar, it matches only the lines in the known set. As I read the question, those are interspersed in other lines the OP doesn't care about.